# Taking a screenshot of the current window and store it as data repeatedly, as to have a screen replay and stable speed

Tags: javascript, html, dom, html2canvas, webpage-screenshot

I am making an HTML/JS document, and I'll need a way to take a picture of the screen every frame and store it in an array, so that it's basically like a screen recording. But I'm having trouble knowing how to do this. What I was thinking was something like this:

```
var pictures = [];
setInterval(function() {
    pictures.push(/**something here**/);
}, 1);
```

But I don't know what to put inside the `setInterval` function in order for it to capture the screen and store it in the `pictures` array. I've seen something to do with `html2canvas`, but I don't know how to use that.

Comment: https://code-boxx.com/take-screenshots-javascript/ this is quite complicated. Basicaly your grab the dom and render it in a canvas.

Comment: Please be careful with your interval. `1` means every 1 millisecond (though the limit is 10, IIRC). [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) might be a better option as it will try to execute 60 times per second (60FPS).

Comment: @So Js: Could you try and dumb it down for me (make it a bit simpler)? I'm not sure I get it.

Comment: @Emiel Zuurbier: Okay. I'll check that out, thanks :D

Comment: @Potato, there is a module that simplifies it. (See answer)

Comment: @Potato why are you trying to do this? Because depending on your usecase, there might be better alternatives. Browser extensions, screen recording applications or (my personal favourite) writing a state based application with a state container like [redux](https://redux.js.org/) and collecting the state changes rather than the images. This allows for [time-travelling through your state](https://redux.js.org/recipes/implementing-undo-history).

Comment: @Stanislas I want a way to have this sharable way of installing a piece of code into the script so that the webpage will be recorded, and if you press a certain button, it'll give you the code, and you can share the code with other people and they'll be able to see what video you have. Just for a test.

Comment: @Potato is it like recording a bunch of CLI commands? Like `npm install ...`, `npm run build ..` or more like recording the running of an installer?

Answer (score 1):

```html
<p class="codepen" data-height="558" data-theme-id="dark" data-default-tab="js,result" data-user="sojs_coder" data-slug-hash="BaQYxRX" data-preview="true" style="height: 558px; box-sizing: border-box; display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center; border: 2px solid; margin: 1em 0; padding: 1em;" data-pen-title="Screenshot JS">
  <span>See the Pen <a href="https://codepen.io/sojs_coder/pen/BaQYxRX">
  Screenshot JS</a> by So JS (<a href="https://codepen.io/sojs_coder">@sojs_coder</a>)
  on <a href="https://codepen.io">CodePen</a>.</span>
</p>
<script async src="https://cpwebassets.codepen.io/assets/embed/ei.js"></script>
```

I made a codepen demonstrating a JS screenshot library. The Stackoverflow snipped was not working. It works fine on codepen. Uncomment the `pics.push(url)` line to save the photo. All it does right now it update the image on a rate of ~60FPS. This is technically not a recording, as nothing is recorded, but it is a pretty good illusion.

Comment: Oh, thanks! Is there any way you could somehow turn the arrow syntax into normal? I don't really understand arrow syntax.

Comment: ()=>{} is the equivalent of function(){}. And sure.

Comment: Okay. So, I'm using Khan Academy for this programming, and I'm not sure what went wrong, but it doesn't seem to work. I've tried it on a notepad HTML document, but it doesn't seem to load in. The image is just that symbol that it shows if it couldn't display the image.

Comment: Okay @Potato, 1: make sure the code is correct. #2, try using [repl.it](https://repl.it), as I know khan academy has a lot of pre-made functions. Just create a new HTML, CSS, and JS repl, and then just copy and past the HTML CSS and JS from the pen.

Comment: Yeah. It works on repl.it, and all the sites I've tried, just not Khan Academy. Did they block something?

Comment: Not sure - they might have blocked the `requestAnimationFrame()` function as it goes quite quickly, and they don't want things to crash, or taking screenshots for security reasons. Not sure. Glad to hear its working though! :) Also please mark my answer as correct if it is working, so other people know it works.